# Hilbert Spaces: Question on a lemma about adjoint operators

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

I 'm studying about Hilbert spaces this semester and the following lemma states some elementary properties on adjoint operators:

[image]

I have trouble understanding why $\;(x,A^* Ax)\le \vert \vert x \vert \vert\;\vert \vert A^* Ax \vert \vert\;$. If I had $\; \vert (x,A^* Ax) \vert \;$, then the above inequality would follow from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality. So my question is, why does this hold?

Is it true to claim that $\; \vert (x,A^* Ax) \vert \;=\;(x,A^* Ax)\;$ since $\;(x,A^* Ax)=\; {\vert \vert Ax \vert \vert}^2\;$?

Any help would be valuable. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: $0 \leq (Ax,Ax) = (x,A^*Ax)$ (aka $A^*A$ is a positive operator).

Comment: @AndréS. that's why $\; \vert (x,A^* Ax) \vert \;=\;(x,A^* Ax)\;$? So basically this holds from Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, right?

Comment: $(Ax,Ax) = \lVert Ax \rVert^2$, which is a positive real number. CS inequality gives you that $\lvert (x,y) \rvert \leq \lVert x \rVert \lVert y \rVert$ for all $x,y \in H$.

Comment: @AndréS. Ok. I 've got it. Thank you!